# Task.IsCompleted not returning correct task state

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I'm trying to capture the state of a long running task during the `Form1_FormClosing` event.

The long running task comprises of async/await calls using the HttpClient.

When I start the task running it runs in loop until cancelled. However, when I close the form with the task still running the task status is not as expected and showing status `RanToCompletion` and `IsCompleted==true`

I've replicated the problem using method `RunLongRunningMethodTest`

`Task.Delay(2000);` works okay but `await Task.Delay(2000);` replicates the same issue. I'm not sure how to get around the fact that `GetUrl` must also be async due to the GetAsync method.

How can I fix the code below so that Form1_FormClosing correctly reports that the task is still running if closed while it runs? I want to check the task state and cancel if still running and wait for the cancel to complete.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static HttpClient client { get; set; }
        private Task task { get; set; }
        private CancellationTokenSource cts { get; set; }
        private bool buttonStartStopState { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void RunLongRunningMethodTest(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    }

                    Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
                    Task.Delay(2000); // task.IsCompleted = false - Works okay
                    //await Task.Delay(2000); // task.IsCompleted = true - Not correct
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // Just exit without logging. Operation cancelled by user.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Report Error
            }
        }

        private async void RunLongRunningMethod(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    }

                    var success = await GetUrl("https://www.bbc.co.uk/");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // Just exit without logging. Operation cancelled by user.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Report Error
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> GetUrl(string url)
        {
            if (client == null)
            {
                client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true, AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip });
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.bbc.co.uk/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "https://www.bbc.co.uk/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Add("Keep-Alive");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DNT", "1");
            }

            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return true;
        }

        private void buttonStartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonStartStopState = !buttonStartStopState;
            if(buttonStartStopState)
            {
                cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                task = new Task(() => RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token));
                task.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                cts.Cancel();
                cts = null;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {

            if (task != null)
            {
                var taskStatus = $"{task.Status} {task.IsCompleted}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `Task` constructor at all, let alone to wrap around an`async void` method. Return a Task from the long running methods properly await their completion. Only your event handler should be marked as `async void`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem is your use of `async void` in your long running methods. When the code reaches the `await` line, the control is yielded back to the parent, and since the Task does not have anything else to run, it *correctly* reports that it has finished.

So, let's fix that:

```
private async Task RunLongRunningMethodTest
private async Task RunLongRunningMethod
```

The second problem is the use of the `Task` constructor. Not only its use is discouraged, but it is also unnecessary in your code. You should be doing just this:

```
if (buttonStartStopState)
{
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    task = RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token); // will only compile after fixing the first problem
}
```

As an additional note, notice that using `Task.Delay(2000);` is effectively useless, since you are creating a Task that is thrown away.

Comment: One quick question as I cannot find the correct search terms... Is there a difference between `task = RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token);` and `task = Task.Run(() => RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token));` ?

Comment: @pathDongle Yes, there are huge differences. Using `Task.Run` creates a Task that will run using the default scheduler, which normally means that a new Thread Pool Thread will be created to handle that task. The best documentation is from @StephenCleary, look [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html)

Comment: Thanks again, the link has everything I was looking for.