# When to use Task.Run and not

Tags: c#, task

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386881/task-iscompleted-not-returning-correct-task-state) yesterday and still don't understand the difference in using

```
task = Task.Run(() => RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token));
```

and

```
task = RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token);
```

I've read through [Task.Run Etiquette and Proper Usage](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) and it appears to be mostly using Task.Run as long as it's used correctly (not in the implementation)

Is there any other reading material about this and or can someone explain the difference between the two?

My code is below which works okay using both methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static HttpClient client { get; set; }
        private Task task { get; set; }
        private CancellationTokenSource cts { get; set; }
        private bool buttonStartStopState { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async Task RunLongRunningMethod(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    }

                    // Some CPU bound work here

                    // Then call async
                    var success = await GetUrlAsync(@"https://www.bbc.co.uk/");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000); // simulate blocking only
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // Just exit without logging. Operation cancelled by user.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Report Error
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> GetUrlAsync(string url)
        {
            if (client == null)
            {
                client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true, AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip });
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.bbc.co.uk/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Add("Keep-Alive");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DNT", "1");
            }

            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} {response.StatusCode}");
            return true;
        }

        private void buttonStartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonStartStopState = !buttonStartStopState;
            if(buttonStartStopState)
            {
                cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

                // What is difference between this
                //task = Task.Run(() => RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token));

                // And this?
                task = RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token);

                // This always runs instantly
                Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} buttonStartStopState:{buttonStartStopState}");
            }
            else
            {
                cts.Cancel();
                cts = null;
            }
        }

        private async void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if(cts != null)
            {
                cts.Cancel(); // CancellationTokenSource
                cts = null;
            }

            if (!task.IsCompleted)
            {
                //this.Hide();
                e.Cancel = true;
                await task;
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider `await Task.Delay(2000);` rather than `Thread.Sleep(2000)`. You're *blocking* a thread when you've got no useful work for it to do. The `Task.Delay` variant releases the thread so it can go and do other work if any is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to the 2 previous answers

- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398804/271106) by [@Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/759558/neil)
- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398785/271106) by [@Thierry V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6230863/thierry-v)

It looks like you are running inside WinForms which runs in STA (Single Threaded Apartment) model, meaning there is only thread processing UI queued messages.

Therefore when you run `task = Task.Run(() => RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token));` this does everything on a thread pool thread, where as by default the `task = RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token);` will block the UI for the duration of `Thread.Sleep(2000); // simulate blocking only` as your await call will be queued onto the the UI Dispatcher as you do not have `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Overall not running it on a background thread means:

1. Your `Thread.Sleep(x)` or the actual work time taken will block the UI
2. You will put more pressure on the dispatcher as each await will be scheduled to be executed by the UI dispatcher. (in your instance if it is only a single await, it is not an issue, but if you started to do 100's or even 1000's awaits, this can start showing noticeable performance loss!)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever good shout, is that the best way to link the answers or is there a better way to link that I am not aware of and the top link in bingle doesn't provide?

Comment: I'd usually do something like "To add to [Neil's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398804/271106) and [Thierry's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398785/271106) answers ..." though that can be slightly tricky if you're not sure what convention is used by those poster's to select a "familiar" name from their complete user name (of course, you can use the full user name, but some users have some really long and annoying to copy ones...)

Answer (score 7):

Basically, use `async`/`await` *throughout* your code base so that nothing is *blocking* threads.  (e.g. your current use of `Thread.Sleep` is blocking, as I commented).

Once you've reached that point, you've already got hot `Task`s returned by your async functions, and these functions will return as soon as they're not making further progress.

At this point, you have a decision to make. Do you have a long running task that is *CPU* bound? If so, *that* is when you might consider using `Task.Run`, because that explicitly asks for the work to be done elsewhere (the thread pool). It's generally *ok* to allow I/O dominated tasks to come back onto the UI thread briefly, which is what you'll get by default and means that you don't have to do anything special to access UI objects.

Hopefully, at this point, you'll not want to use `Task.Run` at all in your example.

---

But it is possible that your long running task is a combination of truly async I/O operations and some CPU intensive operations, and you still don't want those occupying the UI thread. At this point, you should normally be considering using `ConfigureAwait(false)` on your awaitables. But you *may* wish to also use `Task.Run` here.

In either case, if you're wanting to interact with UI objects again, you'll have to `Invoke` to get back onto the UI thread. Make sure you do this at the right "granularity". Don't `Invoke` 5 or 6 separate basic setting of properties on UI objects. But also don't `Invoke` back onto the UI thread before *actually doing* the CPU intensive operations - they're why you tried to move them to a different thread in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

`RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token);` execute your action immediately in the same thread. That means it can block your UI if your code is in the UI thread.

`task = Task.Run(() => RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token));` contrariwise means that you want to execute right away your action. This line queues the task to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task handle for that work.

Normally, we use:

`Task.Run` when you want to execute a long-running code and don't wait if the task finishes. a calculation in background i.e and

`task = RunLongRunningMethod` normally when you want to `await` task, i.e

```
await RunLongRunningMethod(token);
//this method DoSomeThing is not executed until your your long-running code finishs
DoSomeThing();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
task = Task.Run(() => RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token));
```

Will queue `RunLongRunningMethod` to be executed by one of the threads in the task pool at some point in the future.  The next line of code will be executed immediately.

Whereas

```
RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token);
```

Will execute the code on the current thread, and will not run the next line of code until it has finished.

Comment: In my example though, `task = RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token);` starts the task and does run the next line of code - I think this is where I'm confused.

Comment: @pathDongle It doesn't start a task at all, what it does, is executes it synchronously, and will create a `Task` once the first unfinished `await` is hit, otherwise if there is nothing to return it returns a completed `Task`

Comment: Thanks, this really helps clear up what is happening. I've been wrongly assuming `task = RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token);` runs on the task pool. Am I correct in assuming `RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token);` is the same as `task = RunLongRunningMethod(cts.Token);` except that I can monitor the state of the task in the latter?

Comment: In your second example `RunLongRunningMethod` is *highly likely* to return before all of its work is completed, since it `await`s on an HTTP Request/Response, so it's unlikely to be true that it "will not run the next line of code until it has finished."